# pfSense to Amazon VPC IPsec VPN Tunnel Fails to Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, ipsec, pfsense, bgp

I'm trying to setup an IPsec VPN tunnel with BGP routing from a pfSense 2.3.2 firewall to a recently created AWS VPC.I've installed OpenBGPD on the pfSense firewall.

I've followed this tutorial: https://www.seattleit.net/blog/pfsense-ipsec-vpn-gateway-amazon-vpc-bgp-routing/

My IP addresses are different obviously, but it's much the same. I used route /30 IPs that AWS gave me for the pfSense connection and AWS VPC connections (xxx.xxx.xxx.1/30 and .2/30).

**IPsec Logging**

```
Time    Process PID Message
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[IKE] <con2000|817> INFORMATIONAL_V1 request with message ID 3203043492 processing failed
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[IKE] <con2000|817> ignore malformed INFORMATIONAL request
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[IKE] <con2000|817> message verification failed
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[ENC] <con2000|817> ignoring unprotected INFORMATIONAL from 13.54.50.91
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[ENC] <con2000|817> parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3203043492 [ N(PLD_MAL) ]
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[NET] <con2000|817> received packet: from 13.54.50.91[500] to XXX.XXX.XXX.84[500] (40 bytes)
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[NET] <con2000|817> sending packet: from 203.167.218.84[4500] to XX.XX.XX.91[4500] (108 bytes)
Mar 22 18:17:37 charon      07[IKE] <con2000|817> sending retransmit 4 of request message ID 0, seq 3
```

XXX.XXX.XXX.91 is the VPC's connector interface and .84 is the pfSense router.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this too (but with static routes instead of BGP).  My pre-shared key was wrong.  I was able to get the file over to the remote machine so that I could copy/paste the key and then these errors went away.